# video card not recognized after reformated and cannot install?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, amd-radeon

I reformatted my computer and cannot play any games getting an error saying they cannot recognize my video card, I went to amd radeon got the driver update I need and it says `Installation complete (warnings occurred during installation.) View log for details.`

When I view the log it says this:

```
AMD Catalyst Install ManagerFinal Status: Success 
Version of Item: 8.0.903.0 
Size: 20 Mbytes 

AMD Display DriverFinal Status: Fail 
Version of Item: 9.012.0.0000 
Size: 90 Mbytes 

HDMI Audio DriverFinal Status: Fail 
Version of Item: 7.12.0.7712 
Size: 1 Mbytes
```

(Fail is highlighted) When I click on fail it brings me to the bottom of the log saying

```
Error messages 
Driver Install: user must be a member of the Administrators group
```

I am part of administrators group (command prompt-typed net user in it and Local group memberships *Administrators)

I am on Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit AMD Radeon HD 7770 GTX overclocked or something graphics card but driver shown on dxdiag in display is

```
Name: Standard VGA Graphics Adapter 

Chip Type: AMD ATOMBIOS
```

Not sure how important some of this is but just saying it so everyone knows.

Answer (score 0):

Go into the driver folder, and right click on the setup.exe and do "Run as administrator".  In windows 7 even though you are part of the admin group the default "command prompt" is non-adminstrative.

Comment: it wont work still says the same error message

Answer (score 0):

1. Not sure if this is a tower with separate video card. If so, try to re-seat the card in it's slot (and clean it whilst your'e at it).
2. Remove the driver in Device Manager and re-install (with Admin rights, so right click and run as...)